# Ms-Access trying to use "transfer text" to create a csv file with a unique filename

Tags: ms-access, export

I am trying to use an automated macro to export a Ms-Access table to a csv file. I want the destination file to have a unique name, and I reckoned that using now()yyyymmddhhnn would be a good way to achieve this.

I have got transfer text working ok from my macro, and I have set up an export file spec for the transfer.

I am using ="C:\batchfile_" & Format(Now(),"yyyymmddhhnn") & ".csv" in the filename argument in the macro. This bit works.

But when I try to run the macro, it tells me that the filename doesn't exist and then the export doesn't complete. I am not sure why this is, but I think it is because the export file specification is expecting the destination file to have the same filename and column structure as the source table.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Eric

Comment: Are you really exporting to c:\ ? If so, I suspect that this is a permissions issue in spite of the error message.

Comment: Remou, Thanks for the suggestion. I have tested this now by using various different locations and i am still getting the same message. (btw, The export works if I run file export manually, but fails if I use transfer text in a macro)

Comment: When you say macro, do you mean VBA, if not, how do you feel about VBA? If so, can you post your code?

Comment: Hi Remou, I am talking purely macro. If the problem can only be sorted wth VBA then I will have to get help, i.e. farm the job out.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old thread, I am posting my solution so that it may be usefull for some one else
transfer text works fine, as long as variables are supplied properly, you can check for other options other than filename, datasource alternatively create using file open statement
by opening text file and convert recordset data into CSV format.